# UTF 8 encoding - characters displaying wrong

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

can anybody tell me, how is this possible ? This is my code:

```
<?php

require_once('class.Widget.php');

  try {
    $objWidget = new Widget(1);

    print "Název nástroje: " . $objWidget->getName() . "<br>\n";
    print "Popis nástroje: " . $objWidget->getDescription() . "<br>\n";

    $objWidget->setName('2. nástroj');
    $objWidget->setDescription('Tohle je druhý nástroj!');

  } catch (Exception $e) {
     die("Došlo k problému: " . $e->getMessage());
  }

?>
```

I saved it in UTF - 8 encoding, but when I rum it in my web browser (Mozzila Firefox), it looks like this:

```
NĂˇzev nĂˇstroje: 2. nĂˇstroj
Popis nĂˇstroje: Tohle je druhĂ˝ nĂˇstroj!
```

Why are some characters displaying wrong ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to have also:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

in your HTML code

or add this at the beginning of your PHP file:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
```

you should precise it at the beggining of your php script , your browser may decode to your OS default encoding i think